# How could I deal with this custom Exception?

Tags: java, exception, error-handling

I have this bit of code which depends from a custom Exception thrown by a function inside `findID()` it throws a `NoClientFound` Exception that I made whenever this mentioned function returns a null (The client does not exist).

The IDE suggests that I shall apply that Exception into the code, but in this bit of code, where I need the ID to be null (unique IDs) I "can't catch that exception" since if I catch it, the function will not be executed as intended.

**Question: How I can manage this?**

**Function with the Exception problem**

```
public boolean add(Client c) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        boolean added = false;

        try {
            if (findID(c.getID()) == null) {
                try (BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(
                        new FileWriter(fitxer, true));) {
                    //Add client to file
                    bw.write(sb.append(c.getID()).append(SEPARADOR).
                            append(c.getName()).toString());
                    bw.newLine();//New line
                    bw.flush(); //Push to file
                    added = true;

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Logger.getLogger(DaoClient.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,
                            null, "Error appeding data to file" + e);
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DaoClient.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null,
                    "Error appeding data to file" + ex);
        } finally {

        }
        return addded;
    }
```

**Exception Code**

```
public class NoClientFound extends Exception {

    private String msg;    

    public NoClientFound() {
        super();
    }

    public NoClientFound(String msg) {
        super(msg);
        this.msg = msg;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return msg;
    }
```

Comment: So, `c.getID()` can throw the exception but you want `findID()` to get called even if `c.getID()` throws?

Comment: @JohnnyMopp I need it because that it's the function I require to keep IDs unique. The whole code is not mine, my whole role is to add Exceptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can catch that exception and handle it accordingly. When you catch NoClientFound exception that means findID(c.getID()) is null. So without handling that in the if block you can handle that within the catch block.

```
public boolean add(Client c) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    boolean added = false;

    try {
        // call the function
        findID(c.getID());

    } catch (NoClientFound ex) {

      //handle the NoClientFound exception as you like here

       BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(
             new FileWriter(fitxer, true));
       //Add client to file
       bw.write(sb.append(c.getID()).append(SEPARADOR).
       append(c.getName()).toString());
       bw.newLine();//New line
       bw.flush(); //Push to file
       added = true;

    }catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(DaoClient.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null,
                "Error appeding data to file" + ex);
    }finally {

    }
    return addded;
}
```

Comment: I could add the boolean value 'added' to finally and it will look correct as well, right?

Comment: In this particular case it has to return anyways a boolean value. I'm testing your answer, I will accepted if it works.

Comment: I just saw that you have initialized added with false on the top. so you can return added inside the finally block.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you already have a `null` check on `findID(...)`

```
if( c == null || findID(c.getID()) == null){
    throw new NoClientFound("Client not found!");
}else{
    //add your file writing operation
}
```

and Also in `NoClientFound` class extend it from `RuntimeException`, not the `Exception`.

```
public class NoClientFound extends RuntimeException {

...
}
```

Caller method:

```
public void caller(){
   Client client = new Client();
   client.setId(1);
   ...
       try{
            add(client);
        }catch(NoClientFound ex){
            //client not found then create one for ex...
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            //somthing else  happend
            log.error(ex.getmessge());
        }
}
```

Comment: Could you please briefly explain why Runtime instead of the general Exception? My initial intent was to get any error so I went with extend Exception.

Comment: this is just a quick fix when ```add(..)``` get called and client not found, it throws an exception during run time and your IDE is not complaining when you compiling the code. But the best way is to Handel the exception in caller like if the client not found and then do different operation

Comment: I add the caller method too. I hope it's helpful.